# str_replace usage — MYSQL result to create CSS/HTML class

Tags: mysql, str-replace

I am attempting to create semi-dynamic CSS classes in my HTML page, drawn from the results of a MYSQL fetch. Specifically, I am trying to do something that ultimately outputs something like this:

```
<div class="speaker-firstname-lastname">
```

This would be relatively easy if there was just one word involved. e.g.:

```
<div class="speaker-<?php printf($speaker_name); ?>">
```

But here I'm talking about two words; in the database, the first name and last name are in one column, with a space between them. That obviously won't work, because class="speaker-Joe Smith" results in two different CSS classes (.speaker-Joe and .Smith), whereas I need .speaker-Joe-Smith.

I've attempted to use str_replace to do what I want (either replacing the space with a dash or simply eliminating the space and running the first name and last name together), but my implementation clearly isn't right, as it's not working. I've tried it a couple of different ways, but here's one example of what I've tried:

```
<div class="speaker-<?php  
        $string = $speaker_name;
$find = " ";
$replace = "-";
echo str_replace($find,$replace,$string);
    ?>">
```

What's the simple, elegant way to use str_replace in this context?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
<div class="speaker-<?php $str = $row['speaker_name']; $str = str_replace(' ','-',$str); echo $str; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

In certain circumstances, printf might be more optimal. Here's what I got to work for that:

```
<div class="speaker-<?php printf("%s",str_replace(" ","-",$speaker_name)); ?>">
```